# BLAS: gemm vs. gemv

Tags: linear-algebra, blas

Why does BLAS have a `gemm` function for matrix-matrix multiplication and a separate `gemv` function for matrix-vector multiplication?  Isn't matrix-vector multiplication just a special case of matrix-matrix multiplication where one matrix only has one row/column?

Comment: [dgemm](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemm.f) and [dgemv](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemv.f): F77 double versions of the discussion functions for the curious. Also just wanna inject that is a really important (and often used) special case where special optimizations might be possible even if that doesn't show in the f77 versions.

Comment: also interesting to compare performance of gemm and gemv for vector-matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Mathematically*, matrix-vector multiplication is a special case of matrix-matrix multiplication, but that's not necessarily true of them as realized in a software library.

They support different options.  For example, `gemv` supports strided access to the vectors on which it is operating, whereas `gemm` does not support strided matrix layouts.  In the C language bindings, `gemm` requires that you specify the storage ordering of all three matrices, whereas that is unnecessary in `gemv` for the vector arguments because it would be meaningless.

Besides supporting different options, there are families of optimizations that might be performed on `gemm` that are not applicable to `gemv`.  If you know that you are doing a matrix-vector product, you don't want the library to waste time figuring out that's the case before switching into a code path that is optimized for that case; you'd rather call it directly instead.

Comment: gemm uses the `lda, ldb, ldc` arguments which are the row/column strides and with them you can express the same thing for a column matrix as the `inc` parameter when passing a vector. So it ends up equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

When you optimize gemv and gemm different techniques apply:

- For the matrix-matrix operation you are using blocked algorithms.  Block sizes depend on cache sizes.
- For optimising the matrix-vector product you use so called fused Level 1 operations (e.g. fused dot-products or fused axpy).

Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: is it possible to say, gemv() in most cases has better performance than gemm() ?

Comment: Yes, for an actual matrix-vector product gemv has better performance (assuming you don't compare a bad gemv implementation with a good gemm implementation).
 Having said that, with a gemv operation you never can achieve peak performance.  So the trick for in numerical linear algebra is finding algorithmic variants (so called block algorithms) that utilise matrix-matrix products.

Answer (score 2):

I think it just fits the BLAS hierarchy better with its level 1 (vector-vector), level 2 (matrix-vector) and level 3 (matrix-matrix) routines. And it maybe optimizable a bit better if you know it is only a vector.